# Distributing distinct objects into distinct bins if each bin can hold one object

Tags: combinatorics

How to distribute $r$ different objects in $n$ different bins? Each bin can hold one object.

The book says that the the answer is:

$$n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)...(n-r+1)$$

I guess this is being done looking at the choices of each object.

Why can't we look at the problem bin by bin instead like this
$$r(r-1)(r-2)....(r-n+1)$$
I know I am missing a trivial point.

In general how do you select the thing whose point of view is to be taken in account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It helps to look at extreme cases.

Suppose we have $n$ bins and one object. There are $n$ ways we can match an object with a bin since we have $n$ choices of bin in which we can place the object.  The alternative formula you considered would match all $n$ bins with one object, which would be impractical.

We wish to match objects with bins.  Since only one object can be placed in each bin, we should get zero if there are more objects than bins.  However, if we choose objects rather than bins we will get $0$ whenever there are more bins than objects, which is clearly false for the case of one object and two bins.  Hence, we must choose the bins in which we place the objects.

The formula
\begin{align*}
P(n, k) & = n(n - 1)(n - 2) \ldots (n - k + 1)\\
        & = \frac{n(n - 1)(n - 2) \ldots (n - k + 1)(n - k)!}{k!}\\
        & = \frac{n!}{(n - k)!}
\end{align*}
comes from the observation that we have $n$ bins in which we can place the first object, $n - 1$ remaining bins in which we can place the second object, and so forth until we have $n - (k - 1) = n - k + 1$ remaining bins in which we can place the $k$th object.  Notice that when $k \geq n + 1$, the product reduces to zero, as expected.

Comment: I understand your point. But where was i going wrong???

Comment: Your formula gives zero whenever there are more bins than objects, but we should only get zero when there are more objects than bins.

Comment: I understand that the formula is wrong.

Comment: I have revised my answer.  Let me know if I have addressed your question.

Comment: Yes this addresses my question. Actually i am struggling with this chapter as I always make a trivial mistake. Do you have any general suggestions about solving any combinatorics problem?

Comment: Many people have trouble when they first encounter combinatorics problems since it is not always obvious what formula can be applied.  Read each question slowly to determine what is being asked.   Ask yourself questions such as does order matter?  Are we considering arrangements or subsets?  In a situation such as this when you are deciding between two possible formulas, test extreme cases.  Does the formula make sense when you have only one object?  Does it make sense when there are more objects than bins?

Comment: How to test for extreme cases? I guess this will help a lot. Can you give an examples?? THANKS for sharing your valuable time.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig sir we know that n objects distribution to n different bins such that each can have atleast 1 in it is given by stirling formula  , but how can it be proven to be equal to n! only ?

Comment: @ProblemDestroyer The Stirling number $S(n, k)$ is the number of ways to distributing $n$ distinct objects to $k$ indistinguishable bins when no bin is left empty.  $S(n, n) = 1$ since the only way to distribute $n$ distinct objects to $n$ indistinguishable bins when no bin is left empty is to place one object to each bin.  To count the number of distributions of $n$ distinct objects to $n$ distinct bins, we multiply $S(n, n)$ by the $n!$ ways we can label those bins, which gives $S(n, n)n! = 1 \cdot n! = n! = P(n, n)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot Sir , is there a algebra based proof somewhere too in the site ?

Comment: @ProblemDestroyer  Do you mean an induction proof?

Comment: Yes Sir indeed .

Comment: @Problem Destroyer We wish to show that the number of ways of distributing $k$ distinct objects to $n$ distinct boxes is $P(n, k) = n(n - 1)(n - 2) \cdots (n - k + 1)$.  Let's fix $n$ and induct on $k < n$.  If $k = 1$, then there are $n$ ways to place the object.  Suppose the statement is true for $k = m < n$.  Then $P(n, m) = n(n  - 1)(n - 2) \cdots (n - m + 1)$.  Now suppose $k = m + 1 \leq n$.  By the induction hypothesis, we can place the first $m$ objects in $P(n, m)$.

Comment: @ProblemDestroyer  Since $m$ objects have already been placed, there are $n - m$ boxes in which we could place the $(m + 1)$st objects.  By the Multiplication Principle, the number of ways we can distribute $m + 1$ distinct objects to $n$ boxes is $P(n, m)(m + 1) = n(n - 1)(n - 2) \cdots (n - m + 1)(n - m)$.  Thus, $P(m) \implies P(m + 1)$ for each positive integer $m < n$.  Therefore, the number of ways we can distribute $k \leq n$ distinct objects to $n$ distinct boxes if each object is placed in a different box is $P(n, k) = n(n - 1)(n - 2) \cdots (n - k + 1)$.

Answer (score 0):

If we look at the problem bin by bin then the question is something similar like this:

- Given $n$ boxes, how many ways are there to put $n$ boxes on $r$ objects if each box can only be placed on one object?
- Otherwise, this question is similar to: Given $n$ different boxes, how many  ways are there to put $r$ objects on each box if each object can only be placed on one box?

We can generalize it like this:

If we need to distribute $r$ objects into $n$ groups, each group hold **exactly** one object (not each object must be in **exactly** one group, which is not possible because there may be some leftover objects) then the answer is $n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)...(n-r+1)$.

Answer (score 0):

You can think of two steps: first select $r$ objects in $r!$ ways, then put them into $n$ boxes in ${n\choose r}$ ways. Hence:
$$r!\cdot {n\choose r}=r!\cdot \frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}=(n-r+1)(n-r+2)\cdots (n-1)n.$$